# .NET regular expressions how to match a string that does not contain a word at a specific position

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

If I have a text line such as "so and so bit mike" where so and so could be any group of words with any group of spaces in it, what would a regular expression look like that would match

"so and so bit mike" but not "so and so really bit mike"

The only way I can think of to match so and so is `.*`, but `.* (?!really)bit mike` still matches.

Please note, for my purposes I need this to work with a single regex expression.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, if "so and so" can be anything, who's to say that it can't be, from your example, "so and so really"?

Comment: what if we were to assume that anything besides "so and so really" is possible?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, that's the issue, anything can prefix "bit mike".  You are basically saying I know it needs to end with "bit mike" and anything can come before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.* (?!really)bit mike` matches. in fact your negative lookahead is useless there because you're basically saying the next six characters must not be "really", but then you state that they must be "bit mi". No string can match "bit mi" and "really" at the same time so if:

`.* bit mike` matches a string then so does `.* (?!really)bit mike`

I don't know if this is the simplest way, but try using a negative lookbehind instead of a lookahead:

`.*(?<!really) bit mike`

Which says that the be six characters before `bit mike` which cannot be the string really

Comment: if I were to use (.*)(?<!really) bit mike, would the (.*) capture whatever so and so is?

Comment: @pquest Yes, lol good timing. I just posted that in reply to your comment on drf's post.

Comment: haha sorry about asking twice! I wasn't sure if you would also see the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might have used a negative lookahead (`(?!...)`) when you meant to use a negative lookbehind (`(?<!...`).  The pattern:

```
(?<!really )bit mike
```

will match

```
so and so bit mike
```

but not

```
so and so really bit mike
```

Comment: is the negative lookbehind pattern capturing? This is for a replace statement, where I need to know what "so and so" actually was.

Comment: @pquest, no the lookahead won't capture anything. But if you want to capture "so and so" you should wrap the `.*` in parenthesis like: `(.*)(?<!really) bit mike`

Comment: It's not capturing, so `(.*(?<!really)) bit mike` should capture "so and so" if the pattern matches.

Comment: the way you have both written this wouldn't the captured pattern be "so and so " rather than "so and so" *note the space at the end*

Comment: @pquest: `(.*(?<!really ))bit mike` would include the trailing space.